# Jquery Ie8 or less scrolling script error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have recently been working on a website for a friend of mine to help her sell Bracelets online using google checkout.  I have tried to make the site compatible with as many browesers and phones/tablets as possible while still being functional.

I ran into an issue after I implemented the jQuery Plugin that is available at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/floatobject

It works fine in all browsers and phones and tablets with the exception of IE8 or less.  I *made the fatal mistake of not testing on all browsers before sending it out live.*  It appears that the section that errors out in my code in IE8 or less is at:
imgBigger.makeFloat({x:"current",y:"current"});

**The live version of the site is available at** http://www.mldubz.com/exist.html

Please review.  To give credit, the base design is from a 'tutorialzine' tutorial although modified throughout the site and the popup div design for the images on this page (the scrolling of which is what I am having trouble with) is from *queness* however the scrolling, resizing, and centering effects were done with jquery and the above described plugin.

I tried adding var before every variable declare and ensuring jquery and all other scripts loaded properly, but I must be missing something.  My best guess is that I'm missing something really obvious.  Thanks in advance, grateful for any input, even if its a suggestion!

*Note:  Implemented the add to cart buttons and the xua fix for google checkout's shopping cart and fixed as many of the nonvalidating items as possible this early AM.*

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem.  Since I am using the X UA meta tag to force IE 8 support:

I didn't realize that IE 8 and under diddn't supprt $(document).scroll, rather I needed to use $(window), which seems to be fairly cross browser.

Everything is working with that change.  There is a "bug" that if you click the mask area within 1 second, not all of the elements that are given .hide() dissapear, probably because they are still animating.  I am new to jquery, so I am sure I will figure that out soon enough with some more research.  I could tighten the timeframe, but that defeats the purpose of animating it.

Regardless, that doesnt hurt the site in any way as most of the elements stay out of the way of any pertinant site use, and the user can still close them with a click or a tap,or worst case by reopening the image and then closing again after the animation completes.

So I found my answer!  Thanks.  The one bummer is that the XUA tag doesnt validate, but google will probably fix thier cart someday anyway.  Or in the alternative, perhaps someone will find a way to force IE to be backwards compatible successfully with conditional comments or the like.